# "pre-commit" not running in Linux

Tags: git, npm, pre-commit

I believe this should work as pre-commit will run anything defined in scripts.

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "lint-staged",
  }, 
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint"
  ],
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.jsx": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.scss": [
      "stylelint --syntax=scss",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

Console with link not running

```
hutber@hutber-blade /var/www/shipamax-web/frontend $ git add tests/
hutber@hutber-blade /var/www/shipamax-web/frontend $ git commit -m"another test"
[chore/create-circleci-build-rebase 5ff3f76] another test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
hutber@hutber-blade /var/www/shipamax-web/frontend $
```

**Folder Structure**

```
- /.git
- /frontend
--all fe code
--package.json
```

Running
Linux Mint 18.3
node v8
npm v5

**[Edit]**

Post running `npm install pre-commit -D` inside of `./frontend`
[image]

Folder structure
[image]

so I removed `npm pre-commit` and created a  `pre-commit` file inside `/.git/hooks` just to see if it would rename the file, no such luck:

[image]

Comment: and `pre-commit` is in your `devDependency`? The page for pre-commit says that it modifies `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and moves the old one to `.git/hooks/pre-commit.old` -do you see those files?

Comment: Good point, I do not see these files.

Comment: did you manually add pre-commit to your dependencies in `package.json`? You probably have to use npm to install it so it knows to add those hooks to your git package. Run `npm install --save-dev pre-commit` so it installs correctly

Comment: Just tried this and have updated my question to show the findings, but it did not solve my issues

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't see a `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file created by `npm install --save-dev pre-commit` (from [the npm pre-commit package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit)), you won't get any pre-commit action.

From the [`observing/pre-commit/install.js`](https://github.com/observing/pre-commit/blob/master/install.js#L26-L28) check the logs to see if the plugin does detect your .git folder (and if it is the right one)

```
console.log('pre-commit:');
console.log('pre-commit: Found .git folder in', git);
```

Comment: I will have to check the logs, I'll report back, thanks